# CSS ⎼ 3 div-s fit to height

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 3 div-s inside a div, I want to put a picture in red area which have a `500px` height, I want to fix red height area to `500px` and want to stretch other div-s to fill the pages, I don't know hot fit that, also tests put `50%` to each blue div-s but don't worked.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <div>
        <div style="background-color: blue; height:100%"></div>
        <div style="background-color: red;height:760px"></div>
        <div style="background-color: blue;height:100%"></div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: What I want]

Comment: Tip: Try to use the same numbers in your question, your code, and your graphic - it's rather confusing as it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

```
<style>
    *, *:before, *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        zoom: 1;
    }

    .main{
        background: yellow;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .box{
        background: blue;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    .image{
        background: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        display: table-row;
    }
</style>

<div class="main">
    <div class="box">#1</div>
    <div class="image">#2</div>
    <div class="box">#1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you skipped the part where he asks for the outer two divs to stretch ;)

Comment: i want to set my main 100% height but in your code after change to 100% i got scroll and page stretched too much

Comment: Yes. This is what I would have written if the original question was clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution: Use a table (they are valid again for layout thanks to html5 and it's presentational role attribute)

Works in "modern" browsers (IE 8 at least): use css display table + display: table-cell etc to use table rendering on other elements

Works when you have javascript: Use javascript. This will lag behind most of the time and might file when the JS engine encounters an error, so it should be your last resort (or actually past that). Example (with explanation) can be found here: http://nicholasbarger.com/2011/08/04/jquery-makes-100-height-so-much-easier/

If it's only about a visual effect: Use a container div for the blue color and 100% height and then center the red one in it (again, multiple ways to achieve that, e.g. tables, table display + css vertical align, ...)

---

Regarding a correct HTML5 solution (using role attribute marks table as presentational according to W3C spec)

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;border-collapse:collapse" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: blue;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red;height:760px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: blue;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Complete working fiddle here (css part is also important for it to work correctly): http://jsfiddle.net/8jFan/

---

Additional info regarding HTML5 + Tables:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#table-layout-techniques

On one hand tables are disencouraged to fix layouting ("Tables should not be used as layout aids."), on the other hand the spec goes on to describe how to use tables for layouting. As tables are - in contrast to css alternatives - backwards compatible really far (they are used for most newsletters because of that), they still seem to be the better choice to me than css "display attribute hacks".

Comment: my problem is if 3 div are in percent (100/3 = 33) then i can set divs heights to 33% , but in my case one of them is in pixel (760px) i cant divide that with 100%

Comment: As said, use a table or css display: table + display: table-row + display: table-cell (presentational table should be preferred together with html5 doctype, as it is backwards compatible)

Comment: Don't use tables. They render slowly and cause compatibility issues if not set up properly.

Comment: "They render slowly" - how do you mean that? Layouting takes longer in terms of cpu cycles, yes, but they respond to layout changes much faster and as layouting runs in the browser it is far more optimized than any javascript solution. Also tables are BY FAR more compatible than css or javascript solutions - otherwise most newsletters wouldn't be using them

Comment: I'd have to disagree with @RápliAndrás. The rendering for tables this small is negligible. Make sure the syntax is properly formatted, and this is certainly a valid answer. Tables are ancient, and were long used for layouts, so they're still very compatible.

Comment: @bphillips201 Tables are NOT ok for layout due to HTML5. You are confusing CSS3's table-layout to tables which aren't the same thing. HTML's table is for structure. table-layout is for presentation. Do NOT use tables for layout.

Comment: They ARE per spec. Even if they are disregarded, there even is a list of things you can/should do if you use them for layout, which means that it's okay. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#the-table-element

Comment: Read the whole thing: "Tables should not be used as layout aids."

Comment: And then afterwards it states on how to do a "presentational table" "if you use tables for layouting"

Comment: Added working jsfiddle + code + a bit more explanation regarding W3C HTML5 spec (which is still named as "working draft" on many occasions even though the W3C is already working on 5.1)

Comment: Yes, to fix your mistake of using a table for layout for screen readers which will struggle with it.

Comment: You only get problems in the case your table can be interpreted differently to natural reading order. But in the case of what the OP wants to achieve it's not possible, because there are 3 cells after each other (each wrapped in a row), so just a single column. There is no "do I read this t->b first or l->r first?". Also the question is about 2 empty outer cells with an image in the center, so talking about screen readers is out of context. For the sake of argument: Even old jaws versions don't have a problem with a table this simple, but you may try for yourself ;)

Comment: griffin my only problem now is border in table i set them to 0 (border-width: 0; ) but still i can see them , can u help me ?

Comment: Do not use tables to create layout. Read this http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Comment: added "border-collapse:collapse" - this should remove the borders you mean (you can also do border="0" instead of role="presentation" if it's not enough). @Rob: Trying to build software on software which runs on software is stupid - but that's what we do with browsers. So what? I've tried to avoid tables the past 15 years as well, but nowaday I just tend to use what works and is most compatible - and tables fit the job more often than not. ->Maciej: That was before html5 introduced representational tables ;)